# How to filter by name in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need some way to filter "questions" column in my sqlite database, and then get id associated with questions.
This is how i created database (big deal from what i read online)

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///question_database', echo = True) 
meta = MetaData()
question_database = Table(
    "question_database", meta,
    Column("ID", Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column("Question", String),
    Column("Answer", String),
)
meta.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#the-where-clause

Comment: </code> conn = engine.connect()                                                                                      result = (select(question_database).where(question_database.c.ID == 4))                         conn.execute(result) </code> just prints "(4)" even though i dont have this ID in my table.  This is output of conn.execute(result) ---                                                             INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00094s] (4,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

```
stmt = select(question_database).filter(question_database.c.ID == 4)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt)
    print(result.all())
```

This prints all i need.

Comment: This strangely didnt work in exact same database but in other .py file, the solution was to delete all spaces that intelejiidea created before my strings in question_database = Table() function